# Facebook SDK v4.0.1 Failing to compile with gradle

Tags: android, facebook, maven, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am having trouble using *Gradle* to build [Facebook SDK 4.0.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x) in Android Studio 1.2 beta. There is no compile error, but the compiled library is not in my External Libraries. Previously, I successfully had:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
```

However,

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
```

doesn't appear to do anything. From searching, it looks like this version *is* available on [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk/4.0.1). Here is my complete dependency list:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3@aar'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:downloader_library')
    compile project(':libraries:zip_file')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I also have had some difficulties with Google Play Services 7.0.0, hence the comment.

Is there something I am doing wrong, such as a missing dependency or an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

It turns out you can't have comments in your dependencies, so removing

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Fixed the issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem. But removing the comments did not help. what else do you think it could be?

Comment: @prometheuspk I am not sure - but I found it easier to debug on the command line. If you navigate to your project root on the command line, type `./gradlew <target> --info --stacktrace`, replacing *<target>* with your build variant - such as *appFoobarDebugRelease*.